# Access failing for private endpoint in Oracle kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to connect to a private Oracle `OKE` cluster but it is failing with below error

```
 $ sudo kubectl get nodes
 E0912 15:34:18.729625   57232 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
 E0912 15:34:18.730038   57232 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0912 15:34:18.731580   57232 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
```

I created my `kubeconfig` using below command

```
oci ce cluster create-kubeconfig --cluster-id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --file $HOME/.kube/config --region xxxxxxxx --token-version 2.0.0  --kube-endpoint PRIVATE_ENDPOINT
```

It shows the following for the clustername while doing a `cat` on the config file

```
      server: https://10.X.X.X:6443
      name: cluster-xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Do you perhaps need to `kubectl config use-context cluster-xxxxxxxx` to switch to that?

Comment: The VM instance in question has a public IP whereas the OKE Cluster has a private endpoint. So that might be the reason for timing out